# How to set textListener to dynamically generated editTexts in android

Tags: java, android

I have dynamically added a layout with editBox's ,and I want to set textListener to each editBox so that I can can perform some calculations on the values that I retrieve from the editBox's. I am using the the code below to inflate the layout. Is it possible to set a counter on the View object that I am using to inflate the layout. Any ideas are welcome.

```
    public void addField1(View v) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.field, null);
          parentLinearLayout.addView(rowView, parentLinearLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
             }
    int count1 = parentLinearLayout.getChildCount();
                 for (int n = 0; n < count1; n++) {
                    LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) parentLinearLayout.getChildAt(n);
        editValues3 = (EditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(3);
        editValues3.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                            Log.e("inside", "before" + s);

                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                            Log.e("inside", "on text" + s);  
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                            Log.e("inside", "afterText" + s);
                           if(editValues3.getText().length()>0){
                                valCalculations();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: your code looks fine , what's the problem

Comment: the Listener is only getting added to one edit text box

Answer (score -1):

I think you should create your CustomEditText that implements`addTextChangedListener` and inside that custom class make the proper calculations.

Comment: that doesn't make any sense